# What's causing Google JavaScript API discovery to fail?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-javascript-client

I'm using the [Google JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) for the browser, and intermittently it fails with the following exception: `gapi.client.Error: API discovery response missing required fields`. What might be causing this?

My code for loading the API looks as follows, I'm basically injecting a script node into the DOM in order to load the API, wrapping the whole thing in a Promise chain in order to handle when it's ready:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.onload = resolve
  script.onerror = reject
  document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, document.currentScript)
  script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js'
})
  .then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      gapi.load('client:auth2', resolve)
    })
  })
  .then(() => {
    return gapi.client.init({
      discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest',],
      apiKey: initialState.googleApiKey,
      clientId: initialState.oauthClientId,
      scope: 'email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    })
  })
```

The traceback looks as follows:

```
gapi.client.Error: API discovery response missing required fields.
at new wY (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.nyHIlPOzvxo.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNWHYGSUbRcGfoOSnVtpSAoqp5S-Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0:653:491)
at f (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.nyHIlPOzvxo.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNWHYGSUbRcGfoOSnVtpSAoqp5S-Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0:696:457)
at h.o0 (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.nyHIlPOzvxo.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNWHYGSUbRcGfoOSnVtpSAoqp5S-Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0:79:171)
at xs (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.nyHIlPOzvxo.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNWHYGSUbRcGfoOSnVtpSAoqp5S-Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0:82:245)
at Wq (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.nyHIlPOzvxo.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNWHYGSUbRcGfoOSnVtpSAoqp5S-Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0:82:96)
at null._.C.uea (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.nyHIlPOzvxo.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNWHYGSUbRcGfoOSnVtpSAoqp5S-Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0:81:242)
at Ap (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.nyHIlPOzvxo.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNWHYGSUbRcGfoOSnVtpSAoqp5S-Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0:75:300)
```

Comment: I was baffled by this until I checked the discovery service URL directly in the browser and a got a nasty Python stack trace back from a failing import statement in my API code. It had been many months since I had upgraded the Cloud SDK and deployed. So it could be that your API is simply broken.

Comment: I had that error because I didn't wrap `discoveryDocs` in brackets. Perhaps that trailing comma in `discoveryDocs` array is creating the problem. Also checking `apiKey` and `clientId` may help.